# Gradle: How to create javaCompile dependency?

Tags: gradle

I want a task in my top-level build.gradle file to depend on running 'compileJava' in subprojects.  Currently the top-level.gradle file says:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
}

task wrap(dependsOn: 'compileJava' ...)
```

This does not work.  I can say `gradle compileJava` and it runs the "compileJava" target on all subprojects.  But there is no "compileJava" task in the top-level project.

How can I make the "wrap" task depend on "compileJava" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task wrap {
    dependsOn { subprojects.compileJava }
}
```

Comment: Easy enough!  Should have been obvious, but it wasn't.